# 32/64 bit problems with Eclipse CDT on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, 64-bit, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-10.10

I have just recently started running Linux on my PC and I am trying to start learning OpenGL. I am using the latest version of Eclipse CDT as my IDE, and my system is Ubuntu 10.10, 64 bit version.

The problem I am having is that whenever I try to run a build from within the IDE I get the error message "Launch Failed. Binary Not Found."

Ive done a lot of looking around on the internet but I still cant solve the problem. I know for a fact that the binary is built, it can be run from a terminal window. According to posts I have seen the problem is that Eclipse tries to run a 32 bit binary, but GCC 4.4.5 defaults to 64 bit binaries on a 64 bit system. 
* Edit * [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668447/launch-failed-binary-not-found-snow-leopard-and-eclipse-c-c-ide-issue) is where I gathered the above information

Ive seen a lot of information about using the -m32 flag in makefiles, but then I still get the following output in Eclipse:

```
make all 
g++ -o HelloWorld2 main.o 
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `main.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HelloWorld2] Error 1
```

What I would like to know is how to either get Eclipse to launch the 64 bit binaries, or have Eclipse correctly compile 32 bit binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I was able to reproduce the error you describe, so my answer is based on 'reverse-engineering' the error).

In the eclipse projects pane, right-click the project and go to 'properties'. Under `C/C++ Build` -> `Settings`, click the `Binary Parsers` tab, and verify that `Elf Parser` is checked. (I am not sure if it needs to be the only checked parser).

Btw, you can verify the class of your binary file using `readelf -h myBinary.o` and looking at the `Class` field.

Regarding running the 32-bit binary, maybe this post is helpfull: http://stefaanlippens.net/32bit_executable_on_64bit_machine

Comment: Thanks so much, I can now launch and debug the applications and I just have to select some simple options and it all works fine. I still have to look into compiling 32 bit binaries but for now I have enough to start coding.