# Eclipse mac osx: Launch failed, binary not found

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, gcc, binary

Just installed eclipse on my mac cannot run my projects when i build and run i get the following message: launch failed, binary not found.
I've set on project setting \macosx gcc\ and linker\miscellaneus\flags -arch i686 
doesnt work, i am pretty stuck.

Comment: Your build/debug profile hasn't been configured to use the correct location.  First make sure the binary is being built where you expect and second correct the build profile.

Comment: thanks, however i am pretty new on this. so where do i configure build/debug profile?

Comment: Look at section 8 on this CDT FAQ: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ

Answer (score 12):

Hi I ran into a similar problem. I am using the following build :

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Juno Service Release 2

The fix go into  Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Binary Parsers : Make sure "Mach-O 64 Parser is selected"

This thread helped me out: ["Launch Failed. Binary Not Found." Snow Leopard and Eclipse C/C++ IDE issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668447/launch-failed-binary-not-found-snow-leopard-and-eclipse-c-c-ide-issue)
"THE PROBLEM: is that GCC 4.2 (the GNU Compiler Collection) that comes with Snow Leopard compiles binaries in 64-bit by default. Unfortunately, the linker that Eclipse uses does not understand 64-bit binaries; it reads 32-bit binaries. There may be other issues here, but in short, they culminate in no binary being generated, at least not one that Eclipse can read, which translates into Eclipse not finding the binaries. Hence the error."

Answer (score 5):

> The fix go into Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Binary >Parsers : Make sure "Mach-O 64 Parser is selected"

I made sure this was correct, and still recieved an error, so I would say the best solution is to do this step...then, BUILD the project, then press the "play" button and it should work (that is what fixed my problem)

Answer (score 1):

You must build it first, then click run. It will be fine then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the proper binary parser so Eclipse can recognize the executable :

Select the project, then

Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Binary Parsers

For the mac select Mach-O Parser.

I wish CDT just came with these selected, it’d be a simple plug-n-play setup. If nothing else they could add a hint in the error text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,
although i changed the parser as above mentioned it didn't work and i got the same error.

In addition, building the project via the menu solved the problem:

```
Project>Build All
```

I guess the very first code execution with eclipse makes it necessary to build the code separately before pressing the green run button (as i supposed this at least compiles the code).