# Eclipse CDT + windows, is visual debugging possible?

Tags: windows, mingw, eclipse-cdt

Is visual debugging possible with Eclipse CDT under Windows platform? What compiler should I use for this? I've tryed to use MinGW, all is good with the build, but it seems like it is impossible to use visual debugger (breakpoins and so on). If I'm wrong with the settings, please, tell how to configure Eclipse properly.

Comment: My answer [Eclipse Run Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12169583/1322642) may help you a little bit. Create a new `Run Configurations` and set it to debug mode. Look if there is gdb.exe installed.

Comment: new gdb-debugger [gdb-7.4](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.4.tar.gz)