# Eclipse CDT with MinGW GCC Make Error 127

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, mingw

I'm currently trying to set up a dev environment and I can't get a simple "hello world" application to build properly. I have Eclipse and MinGW with GCC installed and have added

```
C:\MinGW\bin
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
```

to my path and am using

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe
```

as the build command. Whenever I try to build, I get the following error:

```
Description         Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [TCP.exe] Error 127   TCP                 C/C++ Problem
```

Comment: Take a look at this question. Maybe it can help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165746/how-to-install-c-plugin-to-eclipse/12169583#12169583

Comment: if you just use `make.exe` (or `mingw32-make.exe` or whatever your executable is called) on the command line does it work? At least that can isolate an eclipse setup issue from a install/path issue

Answer (score 0):

With Eclipse, MinGW integrates seamlessly.  Make sure you have the following added to your environmental path:

`YourPath\MinGW\include;`
`YourPath\MinGW\bin;`

When choosing to make a new C++ project, I personally prefer an `Empty Project` under `Project type:` and ensure that the `MinGW GCC` is listed under `Toolchains:`.  Choose both of those, give the project a name, and select `Finish`.  IF MinGW is not under `Toolchains:` then it is not set properly in your environment or you need to restart your machine.

`Right-Click` the project name to add a new `Source-Folder` (I typically call 'src') and then `Right-Click` on the new source folder to add a `Source File` and subsequently write your hello world code.  So long as CDT is set to `Internal Builder` and you have made no changes otherwise to the Eclipse project settings, your program should build properly and you should observe in the console:

```
12:27:48 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Demo ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\main.o" "..\\src\\main.cpp" 
g++ -o Demo.exe "src\\main.o" 

12:27:50 Build Finished (took 1s.262ms)
```

If you want to enable c++11 within Eclipse/MinGW, just refer to the answer contained in [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)