# Eclipse-CDT: "Launch failed: binary not found" with minGW

Tags: windows, binary, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying alot of the suggestions on all the other identical questions, but I cannot get it to work.

I am using minGW compilter on Eclipse CDT on windows 7 and have run through the following steps:

- installed eclipse CDT
- installed mingw and MSYS
- added C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin to the PATH variable of windows
- included directories in Eclipse under "Paths and symbols" according [How to install C++ plugin to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165746/how-to-install-c-plugin-to-eclipse/12169583#12169583)
- did NOT create a new c/c++ Application manually
- could not find the "Discovery options"
- checked and confirmed that "PE Windows Parser" is check as binary parser

When I press "build all" under project, Debug -> src and Release -> src are created but no execute or binary file.

I cannot find anything else I can do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the exact same thing. I suggest, not a solution, at least you want to make sure the following.

1. Make sure the the source file exists and is written in the folder.
2. Recheck that the PATH is set up right. Sometime we think we did, but the computer does not. In the command line, type the following command to see the gcc installed right and PATH is set right.

   - gcc --version
   - echo $PATH
   - echo %PATH%
3. All things are right as you did above, but it does not work?, Then remove and reinstall mingw and eclipse CDT cleanly. Don't change and keep the default options in the Eclipse CDT. Without any option changes CDT, it should work NOWADAYS. Eclipse CDT(8.7, 8.8) is pretty much stable.

Blessings,

(a debtor)<><

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem every once in a while and it became really tiring checking the binary parser everytime.

I realized that the C project won't build the binary and executable files when the C file name has capital letters. I just USE LOWER-CASE FOR THE C FILE NAME and I never had the problem again.