# Building existing project in eclipse cpp oxygen IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have downloaded this project https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/tree/master/src in to my PC and I am trying to add in to eclipse IDE using File - > Open Projects From File System.
[image: Add projects from file system]

As per tutorial to build Project -> Build ALL option has to be selected.But it is disabled for me.How to build the project.
[image: Build screen]

After building can I run each file separately?
I am new to eclipse IDE kindly help me in running the project

Comment: It looks like you haven't made a C project with the source. I couldn't find the tutorial you referenced, but https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ recommends asking questions on their forum.

Have you tried the instructions on the root readme? https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe
```$ git clone http://github.com/stanfordnlp/glove``` 
```$ cd glove && make```
```$ ./demo.sh```

Comment: You are adding wrong folder. You've made a project out of `src` while make file is located outside.

Comment: @VTT Can you explain me how to add a single file and build it.Build options are not enabled for me.How to set run configurations?

Comment: The proper way to use this in eclipse would be to create a new empty C executable project and import one of the `.c` files into it.

Comment: @JonahGraham demo.sh file downloads the corpus by itself.I have my text corpus.How to edit the path of my text corpus in demo.sh file and run it/

Comment: @VTT I added single file after creating new project and build it.But I am getting following error messageError: Program "make" not found in PATH
Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:/Program Files (x86)/eclipse/jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files (x86)/eclipse/jre/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/eclipse/jre/lib/amd64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Progra and goes on.How should I resolve it?

Comment: It looks like you don't have a compiler installed / set up, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165746/how-to-install-c-plugin-to-eclipse)

Comment: @VTT I have downloaded and built vocab count using mingw.But I am facing these errors Symbol NULL,stderr,EOF,stdin,FILE could not be resolved.