# How to compile C code in Mac OS x Lion

Tags: c, gcc, osx-lion

I'm trying to compile C code on Mac OS X Lion.   I use Eclipse with the CDT plugin.

I always get an error:

```
Launch failed Binary not found
```

If I do `whereis gcc` I get no result.  And if I write `gcc` if the Terminal, I have a  `command not found` error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Xcode to use `gcc`. Be sure to manually install the command line tools:

[image]

You could also download the command line tools here:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=Command%20Line%20Tools%20%28OS%20X%20Mountain%20Lion%29

Comment: I'm not as sure about that one. Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668447/launch-failed-binary-not-found-snow-leopard-and-eclipse-c-c-ide-issue)?