# Unable to run c/c++ code on OS X 10.9

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang, binaries

For some time now I have been unable to run c or c++ code on my Mac running OS X 10.9. See my [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522286/launch-failed-binary-not-found-error-for-c-in-eclipse-4-3-0-on-os-x-10-9-2) for details on what I tried to do about this originally some time ago:

In Xcode running such code gives me the error: "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)", which leads me to believe that it is some problem with clang symlinking to gcc, but I am not sure. I have already tried reinstalling OS X to no avail. Is there a way that I could reset everything related to running c/c++ code short of doing a clean install of OS X and manually restoring my files and apps? This has become very frustrating and it seems that there are no answers! Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you'd like to do, you could avoid Xcode altogether. Have you considered downloading TextWrangler (or any other text editor) and downloading a simple C/C++ compiler as well? There are plenty of resources online to do it that way. I also use Mac OSX 10.9 and chose this method for both C# and C++.

Comment: @daOnlyBG, unfortunately I'm keen on learning iOS programming and so that isn't really an option for me... Thanks though.