# Eclipse error "error starting process. Exec_tty error:Cannot run program"

Tags: c, eclipse, ds-5

I am using Ubuntu LTS 14 on x86. I have integrated DS-5 in Eclipse. I am trying to compile a simple loop program. There are no errors when I build the project, but I face an error,

> error starting process. Exec_tty error:Cannot run program. Unknown reason.

A similar question was asked here and I followed the available answers. It solved the "Launch Failed error" but I got stuck in the new error.
["Launch Failed. Binary Not Found." Snow Leopard and Eclipse C/C++ IDE issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668447/launch-failed-binary-not-found-snow-leopard-and-eclipse-c-c-ide-issue)

In the project settings, I have selected GNU elf parser, aarch64-arm-none-eabi compiler and linker. The code is,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main ()
{
   int i, j, k;
   int l = 0;

   for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
      l = l +1;
      for(j=0; j<100; j++) {
          l = l +1;
     for(k=1; k<100; k++) {
             l = l +1;
        //printf("hello\n");
                      }
               }
            }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am also using an evaluation license for DS5!

Comment: are you trying to run the program on an `arm' architecture?  Most PCs are x86 or x64 architecture.

Comment: @user3629249 yes on x86 machine. but I also tried it to port the .axf file to qemu/arm. it does not execute over qemu either.

Comment: @junaids Have you integrated DS-5 plugin into your existing eclipse or have you installed a complete DS-5 IDE installation?

Comment: @OakBytes I have installed DS-5 IDE

Comment: @junaids can you please post the complete error message either in the post or in the pastebin.com and provide the link?

Comment: regarding the line: `#include <time.h>`  Nothing in the posted code uses anything from the `time.h` header file, so the code should not be including that file.

Comment: please post your compile and link and execute command lines.  Note: I would expect them to be VERY similar to: `gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic myFile.c -o myFile.o`  followed by: `gcc -g myFile.o -o myFile`  and finally: `./myFile`

Comment: please consistently indent the code.  Never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows for many indent levels across the page

Comment: I compiled/linked/ran the posted code, everything worked perfectly, with no problems.  So the source of your problem is the set up of eclipse or DS-5 ide

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may not have the permission to run the program. Check the information of your executable file using `ls -l filename` and try `chmod 774 filename`.

Also, the problem occurs when your workspace is on a mounted drive. If so, edit your build path on your problem explanation and I would guide you to set it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the chmod and got a new error, /home/junaid/DS-5-Workspace/loop_new/Debug/loop_new.axf: Invalid argument

Comment: This is complete error in the Eclipse console. I dont have the reputation to attach an image file! In the proble detail it is written, L3912W: Option"force_scanlib" is deprecated

Comment: @junaids i mean post the error message  in plain text, part of the message may lose some essential information. Also, show us your code